# Bootstrap navbar toggle button not firing and menu not hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar that the toggle button doesnt close anything except my dropdown links, and my menu is not hidden. The menu was hidden prior to me implementing the toggle button.

```
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-header-full">

        <div class="header-full-title img-responsive">
            <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle=".navbar-collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">OUR STORY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">VISIT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">DIRECTORY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">CONDOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">APARTMENTS</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="navStyle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EVENTS</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownMTC pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">YOGA ROCKS THE PARK</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MONDAY NIGHT MOVIES</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HORSES OF HONOR</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">THURSDAY IN THE PARK</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">EVENT SHUTTLE</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HOLIDAY LIGHTS FESTIVAL</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">NEWS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

          </nav>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you have boostrap.js included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `navbar-header` inside the `navbar-collapse`. These should be two, completely separate divs if you go by the default. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Working example Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
      </a>

    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">OUR STORY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">VISIT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">DIRECTORY</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">CONDOS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">APARTMENTS</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="navStyle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EVENTS</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownMTC pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">YOGA ROCKS THE PARK</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">MONDAY NIGHT MOVIES</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">HORSES OF HONOR</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">THURSDAY IN THE PARK</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">EVENT SHUTTLE</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOLIDAY LIGHTS FESTIVAL</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">NEWS</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: That fixed my issue and I was able to fix the toggle button from your example. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors and do you have jQuery and BootstrapJS included (and in that order, jQuery, followed by BootstrapJS) in your project? I'm not sure what you mean by _'the navbar is not hidden_', if you reduce the viewport on my example the navbar is collapsed.